# Saving Documents to CouchDB Urls with Multiple Slashes

Tags: database, nosql, couchdb

My first exposure to NoSQL DBs was through Firebase, where I'd typically store json data to a url like: `category`, then store something else later to a url like `category/subcategory`.

Trying to do the same in CouchDB I ran into a problem.

For example, I saved a simple object like:

```
{"_id":"one"}
```

to

```
   database/category
```

which works as expected.  Then I try saving the following

```
{"_id":"two"}
```

to

```
database/category/subcategory
```

I get this error message:

```
{"error":"not_found","reason":"Document is missing attachment"}
```

Apparently, when you use multiple slashes in a url, Couch understands the resource as an attachment.  If this is so, how does one make databases where data will have multiple levels, like `Geography/Continents/Africa/Egypt`, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CouchDB is not suitable for the usage you described. CouchDB is a flat document store.

You should flatten your structure in order to store it in CouchDB.

```
{"_id":"country-es",
 "type":"geography",
 "country":"Spain",
 "continent":"Europe"
}

{"_id":"country-fr",
 "type":"geography",
 "country":"France",
 "continent":"Europe"
}
```

Then use a view in order to have a mechanism to query it hierarchically.

```
function (doc) {
  if (doc.type == "geography") {
      emit([doc.continent,doc.country], doc._id );
  }
}
```